# undefined reference to `__imp___gmpz_init', building GMP program on Cygwin

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, cygwin, gmp

I'm trying to compile this simple GMP program on Cygwin:

```
#include <gmp.h>

int main(){
    mpz_t i;
    mpz_init(i);
}
```

This is the command:
`gcc -lgmp test.c`

I get this error:

```
/tmp/ccJpGa7K.o:test.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `__imp___gmpz_init'
/tmp/ccJpGa7K.o:test.c:(.text+0x17): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp___gmpz_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea what's wrong? I know it can find the library (libgmp.dll.a), but it doesn't seem to find the function.

Output of `nm /usr/lib/libgmp.dll.a | grep mpz_init`:

```
0000000000000000 T __gmpz_inits
0000000000000000 I __imp___gmpz_inits
0000000000000000 T __gmpz_init_set_ui
0000000000000000 I __imp___gmpz_init_set_ui
0000000000000000 T __gmpz_init_set_str
0000000000000000 I __imp___gmpz_init_set_str
0000000000000000 T __gmpz_init_set_si
0000000000000000 I __imp___gmpz_init_set_si
0000000000000000 T __gmpz_init_set_d
0000000000000000 I __imp___gmpz_init_set_d
0000000000000000 T __gmpz_init_set
0000000000000000 I __imp___gmpz_init_set
0000000000000000 T __gmpz_init2
0000000000000000 I __imp___gmpz_init2
0000000000000000 T __gmpz_init
0000000000000000 I __imp___gmpz_init
```

I tried it without grep and every single symbol in there has address 0 for some reason.

Comment: How did you install GMP? Using `nm libgmp.dll.a|grep mpz_init` could also give some information. Does -m32 or -m64 work better?

Comment: I added the nm output to my question. -m32 totally broke it, -m64 gives the same result. However, doing this made it work: `gcc test.c /usr/bin/cyggmp-10.dll`. No idea why.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This fixed it: `gcc test.c -lgmp`. I just put `-lgmp` last. This seems to be something particular to Cygwin, I tried it with both Clang and gcc-4.9 on OS X and they don't care about the order.

As for the strange behavior with the dll.a file, this is because some *.a files are just stubs that cause linking against the actual cyg*.dll which are all in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin. However, I think this should always be automatic because Cygwin tries to be POSIX, so if you do it right then you shouldn't have to reference cyg*.dll files.

Found out from here:
https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-12/msg00305.html

Comment: There are indeed many questions on SO explaining why the order is important.

Comment: I really do not know, WHY e.g. `-lgmp` need to be as the last parameter. Can someone explain the reason?

Comment: It worked for me (on Windows Subsystem for Linux), but what does `-lgmp` mean anyway?

Comment: `-lgmp` means link against the GMP library, i.e. on Linux to go look for a file like `libgmp.a` in your library paths. If you call a function like `mpz_init()`, the assembly code will be in that .a file instead of your program. The linker tells your program how to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `g++ main.c -o main -lgmp` worked for me.
Basically, all I had to do was putting the `-lgmp` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue while using gmp.h with codeblocks on Windows 7. My solution
1. Install gmp from deval while installing cygwin 
2. Add path the path of libgmp.a and libgmp.dll.a in your editor's linker
3. Rebuild all.